# Adobe Flex ItemEditor

Tags: apache-flex, itemeditor

I have a datagrid column as follows:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn
headerText="Description" 
dataField="description" 
editable="true"    
editorXOffset="2" editorYOffset="2" 
editorHeightOffset="20" editorWidthOffset="60"
itemEditor="com.jono.controls.DgItemEditor" 
wordWrap="true"
/>
```

And a very simple DgItemEditor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TextArea xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
 wordWrap="true" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" backgroundAlpha="1">

</mx:TextArea>
```

Basically, this allows for a small 'popup' when the user edits a cell in the datagrid, allowing for more space to type. The problem that I am having is that the datagrid gridlines show through the itemeditor - i.e. the itemeditor is transparent. Is there any way that I can force it to be opaque?

Answer (score 0):

First try setting the value of `backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"` ... it's expecting a uint there, not a string. This can be confusing, because when you use a CSS stylesheet, you *have* to use the hash format (#FFFFFF).

Failing that, you could try putting the TextArea inside a Canvas in your itemEditor. Set the backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" on the Canvas and backgroundAlpha="1.0".